# Schema not well formed

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I keep getting this error message when I check for well formed (error message below)....can someone please tell me why.. below is a portion of my Schema... all tags are properly closed, and sequence is not misplace....I would post whole code here, however the schema file is rather large.

Error - Line 57, 17: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 57; columnNumber: 17; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_ret' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

```
 <xs:element name="ret">
      <xs:complexType>

        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" fixed="1.0" />
        <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date" use="required" />

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="feed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD element with both attributes and child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946647/xsd-element-with-both-attributes-and-child-elements)

Comment: this was an error I got AFTER I fixed the well formed issue...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare attributes after the sequence. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type):

```
(annotation?,
 (simpleContent | 
  complexContent |
  (
   (group | all | choice | sequence)?,
   (
    (attribute | attributeGroup)*,
    anyAttribute?
   )
  )
 )
)
```

See [the question I linked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946647/xsd-element-with-both-attributes-and-child-elements) for an example.

Comment: Yeah... figured out about an hour after posting this, and forgot to remove question... Thanks