# XSD - <xs:sequence> without <xs:complexType>?

Tags: xml, xsd

I ve a simple XML Data and want to validate it with use of
my XSD File. I want to create the XSD File in any kind of the 
"object oriented" way. Because at least in my opinion it is better to understand/read.

MY XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DSExport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="TestXSD.xsd">

    <Job Identifier="someString1">
        <Project name="someString2">
            <tag1 />
            <tag2 />
        </Project>
    </Job>

</DSExport>
```

MY XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- "MAIN" -->
    <xs:element name="DSExport">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Job" type="JobType">

                    <!-- NOTE: SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE -->
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Project" type="ProjectType">
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="tag3"></xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="tag4"></xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <!-- NOTE: SOMETHING WENT WRONG HERE -->

                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!--  "FUNCTIONS" (WANT TO SEPERATE THE SPECIALIZED VALIDATION OF ALL ELEMENTS)-->
    <xs:complexType name="JobType">
        <xs:attribute name="Identifier" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ProjectType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

I use eclipse. I got any errormessage like:

```
s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'Job' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | 
 key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: sequence.
```

I know how to solve it if I would write every part in the "main" part...
but how can I solve it like "object oriented"? I want to seperate the
complexType definition of every element!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined the Job and Project elements twice. You should move the sequences to the type definitions like this:

```
<xs:element name="DSExport">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Job" type="JobType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="JobType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Project" type="ProjectType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Identifier" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ProjectType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tag3"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="tag4"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Also see: [XSD element with both attributes and child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946647/xsd-element-with-both-attributes-and-child-elements)

Comment: Thanks dude! This worked well and in my opinion this is really readable! it worked fine!